# Como gerar colunas na exibição dos resultados MySQL?

Tags: php

Segue abaixo o script mais próximo do que preciso para gerar em 3 colunas os resultados do MySQL. Mesmo assim não funcionou para eu fazer o teste.

Gerando o erro: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_num_rows()`

O erro refere-se a esta linha: `$num = ceil( mysql_num_rows( $query ) / $colunas );`

**Código completo:**

```
<?php
  $query=mysqli_query($con,"select categoria, link from categorias ORDER BY categoria ASC");

  $colunas = 3;
  $num = ceil( mysql_num_rows( $query ) / $colunas );//quantidade de registros por coluna

  $li = '<ul class="coluna">';
  $i = 0;
  while( $dados = mysql_fetch_object( $query ) )
  {
    if( $i==$num )
    {
      $li .= '</ul><ul class="coluna">';
      $i=0;
    }

    $li .= '<li>'.$dados->bairro.'</li>';
    $i++;
  }
  $li .= '</ul>';
  echo $li;
?>
```

Comment: Coloca o 'i' no mysql_num_rows, e no 'mysql_fetch' também

Answer (score 2):

Você está empastelando o seu script `mysqli_query` com `mysql_query`

```
mysqli_query

mysql_num_rows

mysql_fetch_object
```

O correto e mais indicado é

```
mysqli_query

mysqli_num_rows

mysqli_fetch_object
```

visto que o sistema de gerenciamento de banco de dados relacional, o MySQL, foi descontinuado.